# Recurrence formula evaluating with speacial counting of subscripts

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

Hoping to check some recurrance relationship like this

$a_1 = x$ and $a_2 = y$, with

$$
a_{2n+1} = a_{2n} a_{2n-1}
$$

and

$$
    a_{2n+2} = a_{2n+1} + 4
$$

Tried

```
a[1] = x;
a[2] = y;
a[2*n + 1] := a[2*n]*a[2*n - 1];
a[2*n + 2] := a[2*n + 1] + 4
Table[a[n],{n,1,10}]
```

and

```
RecurrenceTable[
    {a[2 n + 1] == a[2 n]*a[2 n - 1],
    a[2 n + 2] == a[2 n + 1] + 4,
    a[1] == x,
    a[2] == y
    },
a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Neither works. How should I deal with the sub-index problem?
Or am I defining it wrong?

I just hope to get the same result as

```
a[1] = x;
a[2] = y;
Do[
    a[2*n + 1] = a[2*n]*a[2*n - 1];
    a[2*n + 2] = a[2*n + 1] + 4;,
    {n, 1, 10}
]
Table[a[n] // Expand, {n, 1, 10}]
```

> {x, y, x y, 4 + x y, 4 x y + x^2 y^2, 4 + 4 x y + x^2 y^2,
> 16 x y + 20 x^2 y^2 + 8 x^3 y^3 + x^4 y^4,
> 4 + 16 x y + 20 x^2 y^2 + 8 x^3 y^3 + x^4 y^4,
> 64 x y + 336 x^2 y^2 + 672 x^3 y^3 + 660 x^4 y^4 + 352 x^5 y^5 +
> 104 x^6 y^6 + 16 x^7 y^7 + x^8 y^8,
> 4 + 64 x y + 336 x^2 y^2 + 672 x^3 y^3 + 660 x^4 y^4 + 352 x^5 y^5 +
> 104 x^6 y^6 + 16 x^7 y^7 + x^8 y^8}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Method-1

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a[1] = x;
a[2] = y;
a[n_?OddQ] := a[n - 1] a[n - 2];
a[n_?EvenQ] := a[n - 1] + 4;
Table[a[i], {i, 1, 10}]//Expand
```

- Method-2:

Since the initial condition `a[2]==y,a[1]==x` may not satisfies the recurrence condition `a[2n+2]==a[2n+1]+4`, so we have to ignore `a[1]` and start from `a[2]==y`. That is if we set `a[2n+1]` be `α[n]` and set `a[2n]` be `β[n]`, then the result should be `{x,β[1],α[1],β[2],α[2],β[3],α[3],...}`,`RecurrenceTable` work now.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
s = RecurrenceTable[{α[
       n] == β[n]*α[n - 1], β[
       n + 1] == α[n] + 4, α[1] == x*y, β[1] == 
      y}, {β[n], α[n]}, {n, 1, 4}] // Flatten // Expand
Join[{x}, s]
```